# Unrecognizable Message From PROGMEM char*

Tags: arduino-uno, progmem

I'm using a PROGMEM char* to store a massive array. When I try to print a certain part of the array, the message comes out mangled. How do I fix this?

The output should be "Poliwag", but it comes out as "arow".

```c
#include <TrueRandom.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#define numPokemon 151
PROGMEM char* nameArray[] = {"MISSINGNO","Bulbasaur","Ivysaur","Venusaur","Charmander","Charmeleon","Charizard","Squirtle",
"Wartortle","Blastoise","Caterpie","Metapod","Butterfree","Weedle","Kakuna","Beedrill","Pidgey","Pidgeotto",
"Pidgeot","Rattata","Raticate","Spearow","Fearow","Ekans","Arbok","Pikachu","Raichu","Sandshrew","Sandslash",
"Nidoran♀","Nidorina","Nidoqueen","Nidoran♂","Nidorino","Nidoking","Clefairy","Clefable","Vulpix","Ninetales","Jigglypuff",
"Wigglytuff","Zubat","Golbat","Oddish","Gloom","Vileplume","Paras","Parasect","Venonat","Venomoth","Diglett","Dugtrio","Meowth",
"Persian","Psyduck","Golduck","Mankey","Primeape","Growlithe","Arcanine","Poliwag","Poliwhirl","Poliwrath","Abra","Kadabra","Alakazam",
"Machop","Machoke","Machamp","Bellsprout","Weepinbell","Victreebel","Tentacool","Tentacruel","Geodude","Graveler","Golem","Ponyta","Rapidash",
"Slowpoke","Slowbro","Magnemite","Magneton","Farfetch`d","Doduo","Dodrio","Seel","Dewgong","Grimer","Muk","Shellder","Cloyster","Gastly","Haunter",
"Gengar","Onix","Drowzee","Hypno","Krabby","Kingler","Voltorb","Electrode","Exeggcute","Exeggutor","Cubone","Marowak","Hitmonlee","Hitmonchan","Lickitung",
"Koffing","Weezing","Rhyhorn","Rhydon","Chansey","Tangela","Kangaskhan","Horsea","Seadra","Goldeen","Seaking","Staryu","Starmie","Mr. Mime","Scyther","Jynx",
"Electabuzz","Magmar","Pinsir","Tauros","Magikarp","Gyarados","Lapras","Ditto","Eevee","Vaporeon","Jolteon","Flareon","Porygon","Omanyte","Omastar","Kabuto","Kabutops",
"Aerodactyl","Snorlax","Articuno","Zapdos","Moltres","Dratini","Dragonair","Dragonite","Mewtwo","Mew"
};
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int value;
String pokemonName = "Missingno";
int currentID = TrueRandom.random(1,numPokemon+1);
// a = CurrentID
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (EEPROM.read(a)!=0){
    currentID = EEPROM.read(a);
    Serial.print("The Stored ID is ");
    Serial.println(EEPROM.read(a));
    Serial.println("Stored = true");
  }else{
    value = EEPROM.read(a);
    Serial.println(value);
    EEPROM.write(a,currentID);
    value = EEPROM.read(a);
    Serial.println(value);
    Serial.println("Stored = false");
  }
  pokemonName = nameArray[currentID];
  Serial.println(pokemonName);
}
void loop(){

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you've written in, the *pointer* is stored in flash, but the strings are stored in *SRAM*. Read [the appropriate documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/pgmspace.html) (also found in the [Arduino reference](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM)) more closely, and do as it says.

```
char nmPokemon0[] PROGMEM = "MISSINGNO";
char nmPokemon1[] PROGMEM = "Bulbasaur";
 ...

PGM_P nameArray[] PROGMEM =
{
  nmPokemon0, nmPokemon1, ...
};
```

And don't forget to copy the string to SRAM as shown further down before outputting it, since `Serial.println()` can't work directly with flash.

Comment: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM has all of this info.